# Get firefox cache from localhost page?

Tags: firefox, cache

So accidentally I deleted the directory of my website with `rm -rf`.
The server is not running, but the page is open on my computer in Firefox.

Is there any way to get the javascript files? I'm in **about:cache** but doesn't make cache from any localhost pages, why? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page is still open, you should be able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

The "Debugger" pane should show and on the left of the screen, you should be able click to select from the "Sources" list to display each javascript used.

Hopefully, they will still load.

Comment: This should work - but Firefox has a annoying habit of only saving snapshots of the scripts etc used on the pages, so make sure the needed files are saved. I would suggest [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) to save with, but installing requires restarting the browser, which would very likely clear the cache.